# How to to implement multilevel accordion with JSF and PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I am new to JSF and PrimeFaces, and I try to implement multilevel accordion, like

```
<p:accordionPanel value="#{view.list1}" var="val1">
   <p:tab title="Value - #{val1}">
       <p:accordionPanel value="#{view.list2}" var="val2">
            <p:tab title="Value - #{val2}">
                <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">
                    <h:outputText value="#{val2}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:tab>
       </p:accordionPanel>
   </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

, but this doesn't work. I also tried to make it with `panelMenu` component:

```
<p:panelMenu style="width:300px">
    <p:submenu label="Values">
        <ui:repeat var="val1" value="#{view.list1}" varStatus="loop">
            <p:menuitem value="#{val1}" /> 
        </ui:repeat>
    </p:submenu>
</p:panelMenu>
```

, but it doesn't combine with `ui:repeat`, throws

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat cannot be cast to org.primefaces.model.menu.MenuElement`

Are there ways to implement this thing and which is the best one?

*** I know about Tree component, but it doesn't suit.

Comment: The error states that a submenu can only have menu elements as children, not a ui:repeat. So try using a c:foreach instead which runs at view creation instead of view-render time. And 'but this doesn't work.' is not 'smart'... State what does happen etc..

Comment: Multilevel accordion works fine, what do you get for an error?